# Will empty <databaseChangeLog> in Liquibase input create the initial DDL scripts for my spring entities?

Tags: java, spring, liquibase

I was trying to generate the initial `DDL (create, alter, drop)` for my spring entities. I am using `Liquibase` and I am new to it.

I learned that the change-set can generate the difference `scripts` for the db. So I was curious if an empty change-set can create the initial scripts for me.

Will an empty `databaseChangeLog` create ddl script for me ? if not how can I achieve this using Liquibase ?

By empty `change-log` , I mean this

```
<databaseChangeLog
 xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
 http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">


     <changeSet id="01" author="hhimanshu"></changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Since I learned that `change-log` can be converted to scripts , how can I generate `change-log` for my spring entities ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer NO. You need to create changeSets manually or use [generateChangeLog](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/generating_changelogs.html) to generate change log from your existing db.

So flow should be:

- create your db using jpa autogeneration (use h2 db for example)
- generate changelog using command abowe
- check generated changelog if it's ok
- add changelog to your application
- execute changelog and check whether everything is ok

Comment: Is there any Git hub Link for Java code that creates the change log from jpa entities? Can you share?

Comment: What I meant was is there any Java code to manually generate the change set from jpa entities?